# WPF windows background color

Tags: wpf

by default wpf window having white color. so what color i should specify for background as a result it will look like normal window which is just like .net 2.0 win apps windows color. please help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to paint the background using a system color brush.

The **[`SystemColors.ControlBrushKey` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.controlbrushkey.aspx)** will return the `ResourceKey` for the appropriate [`SolidColorBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx).

For example, to set the background of a button, you might use the following code:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  WindowTitle="SystemColors Example" Background="White">  
  <StackPanel Margin="20">
    <Button 
      Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" 
      Content="Hello, World!" />
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: Why would you use DynamicResource here instead of StaticResource? Also, why doesn't Visual Studio 2012's Intellisense recognize "x:Static"?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources:              "However, static resource references to keys that are known to only exist in themes or as system resources are not recommended. This is because such references are not reevaluated if the theme is changed by the user in realtime. A dynamic resource reference is more reliable when you request theme or system resources."

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically bind the window's background to the "Control" brush from the system color palette. You can do that in your window class's constructor with this:

```
SetResourceReference(BackgroundProperty, SystemColors.ControlBrushKey);
```